# constructor overloading between template specialized classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, template-specialization, constructor-overloading

In the following code I have a class template and its specialization.

```cpp
template<size_t U>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(double(&u)[U]) : u{ u } {}
    double(&u)[U];
};

template<>
struct Foo<1>
{
    double &u;
    bool specialized = true;
    Foo(double &u) : u{ u } {}
};
```

If I attempt to create an instance with deduced template arguments, then the constructor arguments will only be matched against the generic `Foo` object.

```cpp
double s[7] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
Foo f(s); // will deduce s is of type Foo<7>

double t = 5.;
Foo g(t); // no instance matches the argument list!
Foo<1> g(t); // I must explicitly tell it I'm using the specialization
```

Of course, if the specialized class had the *same constructor parameters*, and I did something like `Foo g(t)` where `t` is type `double[1]`, the instance would be of the specialized type.

So, how come the specialized constructor is also not resolved (or otherwise part of the set of constructors) in this case?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but keeping a reference in your object might not be a good idea. References are not copyable, and you need to think what happens when they arrays you have references to ends their life-time. Depending on use-cases and design it might be better to use `std::array` and keep your own local copy.

Comment: True, this was just the easiest way for me to consider template deduction and water down what motivated the question in my original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only primary template is considered for Implicitly-generated deduction guides, but you can add deduction guide yourself:

```
Foo(double &u) -> Foo<1>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4910e583cd63689d)

Notice also that

```
double t[1] = {5.};
Foo g(t); // deduce Foo<1>, but fails as specialization doesn't have compatible constructor
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain why that's the case? For instance, I could also define helper functions to mimic the constructor arguments and provide the correct object, so how come the compiler can't do that with the constructors?